# What's the definition of domestic use?

Tags: united-states, terminology

My debate team's topic is about the use of domestic nuclear energy in the United States. I have been running into trouble with people saying that anything domestic needs to physically happen within the United States. I am specifically arguing the use of nuclear energy in space through SpaceX. Any definitions of domestic would be useful.

Comment: Is SpaceX's use that big that whether to include it or not makes a meaningful difference?

Comment: @Ekadh Please don't do mass edits of "Thanks" from old questions.  I agree that there is no need for questioners to say "thanks" and if you are improving a question for some other purpose then you might remove the "thanks in advance".  But every edit bumps the question to the top of the home page.  Editing just to remove "thanks" from many questions disturbs the site, by putting old questions back on the home page.

Comment: @JamesK ok, I’ll stop.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't said any definition since people will pull out the dictionary definitions. This is supposed to be politics stackoverflow not English Language stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

[Domestic:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/domestic?s=t)

> 1. of or pertaining to one's own or a particular country as apart from other countries: domestic trade.
> 2. indigenous to or produced or made within one's own country; not foreign; native: domestic goods.

You generally want to focus on nuclear energy produced by the US and used by the US.

You probably don't need to get too hung up on physical borders, so long as the US is the only country involved, than `domestic` is an appropriate descriptor.

since most words **are** open to interpretation, you might want to ask a person in charge if it's okay if the energy in question isn't technically within the US psychical border.